# Why isn't redirected input considered a command line argument?

Tags: c

I'm trying to read command line arguments that have been redirected from a file. The command I'm using is ./a.out < test.txt
And the contents of test.txt is: Hello world.
But the output of my program below isn't printing Hello 
world. Instead it is only showing ./a.out. Why is this?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[]) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Redirection redirect the output you write to `stdout`, or the input you read from `stdin`.

Comment: Furthermore, your `printf` is wrong. The format `"%i"` is for *integers*, and `argv[i]` is a *null-terminated string*. Mismatching format specifier and argument leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Lastly, your code should not even *build!* Much less run. And if you're not using `envp` then you don't have to specify that argument.

Comment: Sorry, I posted an old version of my code. My question is, why aren't the contents of test.txt treated as command line arguments? If I run ./a.out Hello world, my program prints all 3 arguments. However, if I run ./a.out < test.txt, nothing but ./a.out is printed.

Comment: when `argc` is 1, there are no command line arguments.  In that case, input the arguments through `stdin`  Perhaps via `scanf()`

Answer (score 3):

The shell intercepts the redirection commands before preparing the command line for the program:

```
myProg <infile -t >outfile
```

will pass to the program

```
myProg -t
```

with `stdin` and `stdout` already rerouted before the pogram starts. So the program never sees the rediretion.

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of cases, besides simple derirection:

```
dir > myfile.txt
```

Especially you can pipe output from one program to another:

```
dir | more
```

It will send output if `dir` command to `more` command. Since program launch handled by OS shell, it handles a redirection too.

Answer (score -1):

Because the language is defined that way. Suppose what you say is true —

**All** the user input will have to come from command line arguments, but text redirected from a file can satisfy input required in different functions. This *can* be achieved if the input appears as command line arguments.

Consider this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_dict(char *word)
{
    /* code to look up a dictionary */
    int result = 1;
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc == 2 && is_dict(argv[1]))
        printf("%s found", argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

If the program is written that way to accommodate it, then the input would **have to** come from the command line arguments. How would you take input when it is **not** redirected? It would require more program overhead to detect the missing inputs.

Moreover, imagine a text file containing a million words: it is unfeasible to expect each word to arrive as an `argv[n]`.

There are other objections too. Suppose the program prints a series of prompts for responses. The user would have to know in advance what the prompts are, to supply the answers before the prompts appear.

Lastly, if the program is run from a GUI, then all the program's input will have to be edited into its properties before it is run.